# How can I add third-party integration code via webpack?

Tags: webpack

For example, Google Analytics's initialisation code, or Stripe's publishable key to my app's index.html page when building for production with Webpack? Currently, I am just adding them to the html myself, which means they are included in dev too.

HTML views, not JavaScript

Answer (score 0):

You can pass it when you call webpack. Here is the example.

## webpack.config.js

```
var s3Plugin = new S3Plugin({
  directory: path.resolve(__dirname, 'build/public'),
  basePath: 'js_static',
  s3Options: {
    accessKeyId: process.env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
    secretAccessKey: process.env.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
    region: process.env.AWS_REGION ? process.env.AWS_REGION : ''
  },
  s3UploadOptions: {
    Bucket: process.env.AWS_BUCKET
  },
  cloudfrontInvalidateOptions: {
    DistributionId: process.env.CLOUDFRONT_DISTRIBUTION_ID,
    Items: ["/*"]
  },
  cdnizerOptions: {
    defaultCDNBase: '//' + process.env.CLOUDFRONT_URL
  }
})
```

Then,

```
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID="You Key" AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY="You Key" AWS_BUCKET="Bucket Name" AWS_REGION="Region Name" CLOUDFRONT_DISTRIBUTION_ID="Distribution ID" CLOUDFRONT_URL="cloud front url" BUILD_DEV=0 BUILD_STAGING=1 webpack -p --colors --display-error-details --config ./webpack.config.js
```

I recommend you to check webpack-howto, too. Tips from Instagram. https://github.com/petehunt/webpack-howto

Comment: I want to add them to HTML not JavaScript

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to implement. In my case, I'm using Express.js and handlebars and just passing variables to them.

Comment: Not possible with raw html? Must I use a templating language?

Comment: HTML file is static, so you cannot pass variables dynamically.